# Prove that $\forall x \in \Bbb R^+:x+0=x\cdot 1=x$

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

> Let $\Bbb R^+=\{x\in\Bbb R \mid x>0\}$ and $x,y\in\Bbb R^+$. We define multiplication operation $(\cdot)$ on $\Bbb R^+$  and addition operation $(+)$ on $\Bbb R$ by $$x\cdot y:=\inf\{r\cdot s\mid r,s\in\Bbb Q \text{ and } x<r  \text{ and } y<s\}$$ $$x+ y:=\inf\{r+ s\mid r,s\in\Bbb Q \text{ and } x<r  \text{ and } y<s\}$$
>
> Prove that $$\forall x \in \Bbb R^+:x+0=x\cdot 1=x$$

Does my attempt look fine or contain logical flaws/gaps? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

1. $x+0=x$.

By definition, we have:

- $x=\inf \{r \mid r\in\Bbb Q,x<r\}=\inf A$
- $x+0=\inf \{r+s \mid r,s\in\Bbb Q,x<r,0<s\}=\inf B$

$b\in B \implies b=r+s$ for some $r,s\in\Bbb Q$ such that $x<r,0<s$ $\implies b>r$ for some $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $x<r$ $\implies b>r$ for some $r\in A$ $\implies \inf A \le \inf B \implies x \le x+0$.

Assume the contrary that $x<x+0$. By the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there exist $p\in \Bbb Q$ such that $x<p<x+0$ and $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $x <r<p$. Let $p=r+s>r$. Then $s\in\Bbb Q$ and $s>0$. It follows that $x+0>p$ where $p=r+s$ such that $r,s\in\Bbb Q,x<r,0<s$. This is a contradiction.

2. $x\cdot 1=x$

By definition, we have:

- $x=\inf \{r \mid r\in\Bbb Q,x<r\}=\inf A$
- $x\cdot 1=\inf \{r\cdot s \mid r,s\in\Bbb Q,x<r,1<s\}=\inf B$

$b\in B \implies b=r\cdot s$ for some $r,s\in\Bbb Q$ such that $x<r,1<s$ $\implies b>r$ for some $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $x<r$ $\implies b>r$ for some $r\in A$ $\implies \inf A \le \inf B \implies x \le x\cdot 1$.

Assume the contrary that $x<x\cdot 1$. By the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there exist $p\in \Bbb Q$ such that $x<p<x\cdot 1$ and $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $x <r<p$. Let $p=r\cdot s>r$. Then $s\in\Bbb Q$ and $s>1$. It follows that $x\cdot 1>p$ where $p=r\cdot s$ such that $r,s\in\Bbb Q,x<r,1<s$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Here is an edit in one of your paragraphs: You write: "$b \in B \implies b=r+s$ for some $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r,0<s \implies b>r$ for some $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r$ [and so $b > x= \inf A$ so $inf A \leq inf B$]

Comment: Hi @Michael, I don't understand what you meant. Is the reasoning in that paragraph wrong? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: You concluded $b>r$ and $r>x$, so therefore we directly get $b>x$.  That is what you want since $x$ is already defined as $\inf A$. In fact the sentence would be easier to read if it was just "$b \in B$ implies $b = r+s$ for some $r, s \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<r, 0<s$. So $b=r+s>r>x = \inf A$." (and since $b > \inf A$ for all $b \in B$ it holds that $\inf B \geq \inf A$.) It would also help if you explicitly defined the sets $A$ and $B$, though I know what you meant.

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thank you so much for your detailed comment! Now I got your point.

Comment: For the other parts, I don't feel confident helping since you are proving $x=x+0$, which is so basic that I'm not sure what you are allowed to use to prove this (in fact this is usually treated as an axiom).  You use facts about inequalities and density of rationals in $\mathbb{R}$, I'm not sure if these facts are proven before or after knowing $x=x+0$, so I'm not sure if you are allowed to use them.

Comment: Hi @Michael! I think your comments deserve to be posted as an answer and I will accept it. Actually, I am using the textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech. The authors first constructed $\Bbb N$ and its operations, then $\Bbb Z$ and its operations, then $\Bbb Q$ and its operations. The operations on the latter are defined from those on the former. The authors construct $\Bbb R$ by Dedekind cuts :)

Comment: Maybe I'll do that tomorrow, or perhaps someone will post a better answer by then.